# Mod rewrite only when directory exists

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory

I have a directory structure as follows:

```
/gallery
----index.php
----/23XASDTAGH
----/24XGA43KJA/
```

I'd like to use mod rewrite to rewrite if a directory exists. so:

`www.example.com/gallery/23XASDTAGH/`

becomes

`www.example.com/gallery/index.php?gallery=23XASDTAGH`

but i'd like to do this silently, so no changes happen to the url. now i have this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/ -d
RewriteRule (.*) /gallery/index.php?gallery=$1 [L]
```

which works with

`www.example.com/gallery/23XASDTAGH/`

but the odd thing is when i leave the trailing slash off the end it changes the url to

`www.example.com/gallery/23XASDTAGH/?gallery=23XASDTAGH`

how can i get it to work with or without the trailing slash?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally figured it out, i needed a `?/` at the end of my expression in the rewrite rule to say that the slash was optional. Why do regular expressions have to be so <s>hard</s> easy. 8-)

correct expression:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     -d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?/$    /gallery/index.php?gallery=$1 [L]
```

Comment: That's in my answer, so what is it you figured out? On the other hand, what you are doing is wrong. The question mark must be after the optional character, not before. You are making the regex group optional, not the slash.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following will do the trick

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule (.*) /gallery/index.php?gallery=$1 [L]
```

Second line checks that the requested filename is a directory and if it is then the third line does the actual rewrite

To try and deal with the trailing slash problem, maybe this, or something like this will work

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.*)/?$
RewriteCond %1 -d
RewriteRule (.*)/$ /gallery/index.php?gallery=$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: Yes Dom, that's basically it. except with i add a trailing slash to the url it doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(gallery)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_=]+)/?$ http://www.example.com/$1/index.php?$1=$2 [R=301,L]
```

Permanent redirect the entered URL (The one in the browser address bar):

`www.example.com/gallery/23XASDTAGH` or `www.example.com/gallery/23XASDTAGH/`to:

`www.example.com/gallery/index.php?gallery=23XASDTAGH`